# iphone consecutive animations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I'm wondering what the best way is to implement a series of different animations. If I call the following method and try to animate the same object right, left, and up, for instance, it won't work, because the compiler doesn't deal with them in a linear fashion, and I end up with my object simply going up (skipping the steps to go right and left):

```
    -(IBAction)clickStart
{
    [self Animation1];
    [self Animation2];
    [self Animation3];

}
```

Now I could to this, but it somehow feels cumbersome and weird to me. Consider this is the method for Animation1:

```
[pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation1" context:nil]; // Begin animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(Animation2)];

    [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];

    [UIView commitAnimations]; // End animations
```

And then I could do the same in Animation2, i.e. to call Animation3 once it is done. But to be honest, this is very confusing and not a very clear coding method. Is there anyway to get a more 'linear' code like the one I've suggested at the beginning (which doesn't work), or will I simply have to live with the selector-method?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't have to support iOS < 4:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    // animation 1
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        // animation 2
    } completion^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            // animation 3
        }];
    }];
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even though it looks confusing at first sight, I think this is actually much clearer than to do the same thing with the selector method. At least I have the code presented in a linear fashion. Thanks!

Comment: Blocks mean you don't have to store animation-state at the class level which generally leads to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 2):

We created a component for chaining animation steps declaratively using blocks ([CPAnimationSequence on Github](https://github.com/yangmeyer/CPAnimationSequence)).

It gives you very readable code, something like this:

```
[[CPAnimationSequence sequenceWithSteps:
    [CPAnimationStep           for:0.25 animate:^{ self.imageView.alpha = 0.0; }],
    [CPAnimationStep           for:0.25 animate:^{ self.headline.alpha = 0.0;  }],
    [CPAnimationStep           for:0.25 animate:^{ self.content.alpha = 0.0;   }],
    [CPAnimationStep after:1.0 for:0.25 animate:^{ self.headline.alpha = 1.0;  }],
    [CPAnimationStep           for:0.25 animate:^{ self.content.alpha = 1.0;   }],
    nil]
runAnimated:YES];
```

Compared to the usual block-based approach (described well by Max), it has the advantage of matching the intent and its representation: a *linear sequence* of steps to animate. We elaborated on this topic in [an article on our iOS development blog](http://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=43).